# Data e Hora e Fim de Semana

Tags: php

Eu tenho um `script`, que faz agendamento automatico de tarefas.

Através da linha abaixo, eu pego a data/hora atual, adiciono mais 5 minutos, e o script fica agendado.

```
$timeStamp = strtotime("+5 minutes", time());
```

Mas, quando for fim de semana (Sábado e Domingo), eu quero que ele agende com a mesma ideia, no mesmo horario (da execução do script), Mas que seja para segunda.

Como faço isso?

Comment: http://www.timestampgenerator.com/ este site calcula o time stamp

Answer (score 6):

Primeiro, dá pra simplificar sua linha assim:

```
$timeStamp = time() + 300;
```

Isso evita um monte de operações internas e dá o mesmo resultado. `time` retorna o valor em segundos, então basta acrescentar `5 * 60 segundos`, que dá `300`, para o PHP não precisar fazer uma chamada desnecessária ao `strtotime` e uma complexa interpretação de strings.

Uma vez feito isso, basta testar se o resultado caiu no final de semana, e adicionar um ou dois dias conforme o resultado:

```
$timeStamp = time() + 300;
$weekday = date( 'N', $timeStamp );
if( $weekday > 5 ) $timeStamp += ( 8 - $weekday ) * 86400;
```

- `$weekday = date( 'N', $timestamp)` obtém o dia da semana, sendo `1` segunda e `7` domingo
- se o resultado for maior que `5` (ou seja, sábado ou domingo ), adiciona 86400 segundos (ou seja, um dia, `24 * 60 * 60`) multiplicado por `8 - $weekday`, que dá um dia caso seja `7` (domingo), ou dois dias caso seja `6` sábado, efetivamente jogando o agendamento da segunda.

Aqui temos uma versão com `strtotime`, mais parecida com a sua:

```
$timeStamp = strtotime( '+5 minutes', time() );
if( date( 'N', $timeStamp ) > 5 ) $timeStamp = strtotime( 'next monday', $timeStamp );
```

Ou, mantendo a hora:

```
if( date( 'N', $timeStamp ) > 5 )
   $timeStamp = strtotime( 'next monday '.date('H:i:s', $timeStamp), time() )
```

Mas não se iluda, apesar de mais curta esta segunda versão, ela realiza internamente uma quantidade muito maior de operações bem mais complexas do que o primeiro código, para fazer a interpretação textual dos valores. Em resumo, é tecnicamente inferior.

Comment: @Bacco acho que eu conheço esse `next monday` de alguma conversa, hein

Comment: Pessoal, infelizmente ele seta para Segunda Feira, sempre as 12:00

Comment: Eu preciso que seja justamente o horario atual, que o script foi rodado.....

Comment: A primeira versão respeita o horário e é tecnicamente superior, mas para fazer na segunda, bastaria concatenar a hora atual no 'next monday '. Na verdade eu só postei essa segunda, pq provavelmente alguém com menos conhecimento ia postar, e poderia ser tomada como melhor solução por engano. `strtotime( 'next monday '.date('H:i:s', $timestamp), time() )`

Comment: Ah, entendi. Mas uma vez obrigada. Sensacional suas dicas...